# Integrate unity ads error at the second play

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, unityads

I added [Unity Ads](https://unity.com/products/unity-ads) to my project.
At the first run at all works good and it show that an ad will show, but when I hit play the second time it give me this error

> MissingReferenceException: The object of type 'GameObject' has been destroyed but you are still trying to access it.
> Your script should either check if it is null or you should not destroy the object.

This is my script for the ads :

```cs
public class Monetization : MonoBehaviour, IUnityAdsListener
{
    string GooglePlay_ID = "****";
    bool GameMode = true;
   
    string myPlacementId = "rewardedVideo";

    void Start()
    {
        Advertisement.AddListener(this);
        Advertisement.Initialize(GooglePlay_ID, GameMode);
       
    } 

    public void ShowRewardedVideo()
    {
        // Check if UnityAds ready before calling Show method:
        if (Advertisement.IsReady(myPlacementId))
        {
            Advertisement.Show(myPlacementId);
        }
        else
        {
            Debug.Log("Rewarded video is not ready at the moment! Please try again later!");
        }
    }

    // Implement IUnityAdsListener interface methods:
    public void OnUnityAdsDidFinish(string placementId, ShowResult showResult)
    {
        // Define conditional logic for each ad completion status:
        if (showResult == ShowResult.Finished)
        {
            // Reward the user for watching the ad to completion.

           
            SceneManager.LoadScene(4);
        }
       
        else if (showResult == ShowResult.Skipped)
        {
            // Do not reward the user for skipping the ad.
        }
        else if (showResult == ShowResult.Failed)
        {
            Debug.LogWarning("The ad did not finish due to an error.");
        }
    }

    public void OnUnityAdsReady(string placementId)
    {
        // If the ready Placement is rewarded, show the ad:
        if (placementId == myPlacementId)
        {
            // Optional actions to take when the placement becomes ready(For example, enable the rewarded ads button)
        }
    }

    public void OnUnityAdsDidError(string message)
    {
        // Log the error.
    }

    public void OnUnityAdsDidStart(string placementId)
    {
        // Optional actions to take when the end-users triggers an ad.
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

When you load a new scene, the game objects in the previous scene will be destroyed. To prevent this add the following function in your Monetization script.

```
void Awake() {
DontDestroyOnLoad(this.gameObject);
}
```

Comment: it will be destroyed even if i dont load a new scene